# jdbc metadata getTables to list only table list

Tags: java, jdbc, metadata

i am trying to list tables from a database, when i use the below syntax

```
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%" ,null);
```

this returns me all the tables, views, index, system_tables from the database.

but i need only list of tables from the public schema so i have given the below syntax,

```
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, "public", "%" ,"TABLE");
```

which shows me the following error

```
required: String,String,String,String[]
found: <null>,String,String,String
reason: actual argument String cannot be converted to String[] by method invocation conversion
```

just need to list the tables alone from public schema.

plz help with the syntax

Comment: Pass an array with one value "TABLE" as last parameter. See Brian Agnew's answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) suggests your last parameter should be an *array* of strings.

```
public ResultSet getTables(String catalog,
                           String schemaPattern,
                           String tableNamePattern,
                           String[] types)
                    throws SQLException
```

Answer (score 6):

The signature for `getTables()` expects an array as the fourth argument.  Try

```
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, "public", "%" ,new String[] {"TABLE"} );
```